# How to create auto resizeable text item renderer in Flex MX list?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex3

My Flex MX list has this itemRenderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100%" autoLayout="true" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <mx:Label y="0" right="0" text="{data.hour}" textAlign="right"/>
    <mx:HBox left="0" right="0">
        <mx:Label text="{data.username}" />
        <mx:Text id="text1" text="{data.text}"/>
        <mx:Image  />
        <mx:Button />
    </mx:HBox>  
</mx:Canvas>
```

My problem is : I want the MX Text id="text1" to be multi line if {data.text} grows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Label word wrap in Flex 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138627/label-word-wrap-in-flex-4)

Comment: percentHeight, percentWidth may do the trick.Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538199/how-to-get-a-flex-text-control-to-word-wrap

Answer (score 0):

Set width and height properties to mx:Text component